# Does fetchLimit fetch the first or last index of CoreData array?

Tags: core-data, nsfetchrequest

I just want to retrieve the last stored CoreData value. I'm using the fetchLimit = 1. But I don't understand if this will retrieve the first or the last index of array (not sure if you call stored CoreData Entities arrays).

Will this code below fetch the first or the last? This matters, because I need to know if *ascending* should be *true* or *false*.

```
let requestTDD = TDD.fetchRequest() as NSFetchRequest<TDD>
let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "timestamp", ascending: false)
requestTDD.sortDescriptors = [sort]
requestTDD.fetchLimit = 1

var tdds = [TDD]()
try? tdds = coredataContext.fetch(requestTDD)
```

Code doesn't generate any errors and data is fetched, I just need to verify if correct.

Comment: I tested with output to a JSON. When setting  ascending: true some other than the last value is fetched. When setting it to false, the last index is fetched.  

    "Insulin" : {
            "scheduled_basal" : 1.4,
            "bolus" : 61.15,
            "TDD" : 69.09999999999999,
            "temp_basal" : 6.55
          },   

Question nr 2: Is the sorting an expensive task, if sorting thousand of entries? Does it help adding a predicate with a shorter time interval, for instance 1 day before sorting, or is this as expensive?

Comment: It fetches the first object based on your sorting.

Comment: Yes, this corresponds to what I'm seeing in output. So setting ascending: true would give you the oldest value, which could be useful for other purposes. Do you also know if the sorting above is efficient or expensive when having many thousands of values?

Comment: If sorting becomes slow you can add an index on the timestamp attribute